# How to find which SQL server instance is consumimg more CPU on 4 node / 20 instance Windows cluster?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, windows, clustering

I want to know which sql server instance is consuming more CPU on a 4 node active -active - active - active windows cluster. ?

situation: Windows cluster - 4 Node 
all active, each node has 5 sql server instances, i want to check the CPU utilization of all the active instances, any help ?

Comment: Having 5 instances on a single node is by itself a situation.

Comment: You should use Windows Performance Monitor to determine which instance is using CPU.  Run Performance Monitor on all 4 nodes.

Comment: @Santa - I would tend to disagree.  Having "x" number of instances on a single node is not necessarily a "situation".  If the instances are configured correctly, that can be a valid way of separating resources.

Comment: @Santa Why are you saying that having 5 instances is an issue?

Comment: @ajeh The way I see it, there has to be a better way to do it than to have 20 instances in a Cluster. But these aren't FCIs, I suppose.

Comment: And I think that as long as we are answering the specific question, we should not go above and beyond and criticize the question and asker. Technically, as long as the nodes are configured to the correct max memory limit and can fail over, this set up is almost textbook. We have no idea what his/her architectural requirements are, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Glenn Berry has a set of DMV scripts, in each of them there is a CPU utilization for the last 256 minutes for the instance (query number 40 for SQL 2016 script). Run this on each instance. And if you have CMS setup correctly, you can run the script against a group of instances at the same time.
the link to Glenn Berry's page:
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/sql-server-diagnostic-information-queries-for-september-2016/

Comment: That's indeed what I'm also using :). That or monitoring tools on the node.